# Web scraping returns tags

Tags: python, web, screen-scraping

I'm a complete noob to HTML. I had to look up "tags" and "class" before I wrote this. I'm aware that `urllib2` is the default for this sort of thing now, but I couldn't get my header to work with it properly (otherwise you get a 403 access denied error), so I used `requests` instead.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.grandexchangecentral.com/item.php?rid=4365'
r = requests.get(url, headers={'Referer': 'www.grandexchangecentral.com'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
soup.find_all("div", {"class":"CurrentMarket"})
```

This returns `[<div class="CurrentMarket">219</div>]`, when I would like it to be just `219`. Could someone please help me get the proper output? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty easy, assume the return value of your `find_all` is called `markets`:

```
markets[0].contents[0]
```

Since `markets` is a list, get the first item with `[0]`, and then it gets the `contents` (also a list, thus another `[0]`)

Maybe look at the [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)?

Comment: @user1709173 If it works, click the little check mark to the left of my answer please :D